# Proxy error when using OAuth2 gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0

Hi I’m trying to use oauth 2 to connect my app to a local API.
The authorization request succeed and return me a code on my callback address to make the access token request.
Here is my callback code :

```
def client
  OAuth2::Client.new(KEY, SECRET, site: SITE, authorize_url: '/oauth2/auth', token_url: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token')
end

get '/auth/callback' do
  access_token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], "redirect_uri" => redirect_uri)
  access_token =  session[:access_token] = access_token.token
  @access_token = access_token
end
```

In get_token function, I made a pry to check my connection configuration (which is correct):

```
1.9.3 (#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fb255183e18>):0 > connection
=> #<Faraday::Connection:0x007fb2551817f8 
@parallel_manager=nil, 
@headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.0"}, 
@params={}, @options=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)>, 
@ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)>, 
@default_parallel_manager=nil, 
@builder=#<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x007fb255188760 
@handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp, Faraday::Response::Logger]>, 
@url_prefix=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fb255187b08 URL:http://localhost:3000/>, 
@proxy=#<Faraday::ProxyOptions uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fb255186b68 URL:http://proxy_url:port>, user="me", password=« MyPassword">>

1.9.3 (#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fb255183e18>):0 > url
=> "http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token »

1.9.3 (#<OAuth2::Client:0x007f9bdb94cce8>):0 > verb
=> :post

1.9.3 (#<OAuth2::Client:0x007f9bdb94cce8>):0 > opts
=> {
      :body => {
        "client_id" => "Test",
        "client_secret" => "test_secret",
        "code" => "d3c4661b11ea5e2752852db72e1ce100f2f1804d",
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost:4567/auth/callback"
    },
      :headers => {
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
      :parse => nil,
      :raise_errors => true
}
```

Debug informations from request :

```
I, [2014-08-20T12:01:19.450941 #12792]  INFO -- : post    http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token
D, [2014-08-20T12:01:19.451040 #12792] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "Faraday v0.9.0"
Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
I, [2014-08-20T12:01:19.451203 #12792]  INFO -- Status: 401
D, [2014-08-20T12:01:19.451258 #12792] DEBUG -- response: cache-control: "no-cache"
pragma: "no-cache"
www-authenticate: "NTLM, BASIC realm=\"OUR_DOMAIN_NAME\""
content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
proxy-connection: "close"
set-cookie: "BCSI-CS-925062b0249dae29=2; Path=/"
connection: "close"
content-length: "706"
x-rbt-optimized-by: "riv-olo (RiOS 8.5.1) IK"
OAuth2::Error - Nice page from my proxy telling me that I’m not authentified on the domain
```

When I make a POST request with POSTMAN REST Client using my authorization code, everything is fine and the API return me an access_token.
I don’t understand why the request is passing by the proxy because all my apps and API are on my localhost.

Could someone tell me why this error append using my local app ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your connection to the internet behind a proxy then? It sounds like it's a problem with Postman not bypassing the proxy, rather than anything to do with your application. What OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'am behind a proxy, and I'm working on Mac OSX. And postman has no problem, I can get my access token with it.

Comment: I've posted an answer which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my postman request worked and not those of my app, I used Wireshark to see the difference between them.
In Oauth, my proxy parameters were used by default. So my request went on the proxy IP.
And on Postman, requests went directly on localhost. 
So I changed my client definition to force empty proxy parameters :

```
PROXY_URI = ''
PROXY_USER = ''
PROXY_PASSWORD = ''

def client
  OAuth2::Client.new(KEY, SECRET, site: SITE, authorize_url: '/oauth2/auth', token_url: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token', connection_opts: {
    :proxy => {:uri => PROXY_URI,
               :user => PROXY_USER,
               :password => PROXY_PASSWORD}})
end
```

Now request are send to localhost as expected.
It's ok for local tests, but now I'll need to make conditional assignment of my proxy variables.

Why the GET method were sent to localhost and not POST method ? It's still a mystery !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to hit localhost via your proxy, which won't work. If you're using OS X:

1. Go to *System Preferences > Network*.
2. Select the connection you're using on the left (eg. "Wi-Fi" or "Ethernet").
3. Click "Advanced..." at the bottom right.
4. Go to the "Proxies" tab.
5. In the box at the bottom ("Bypass proxy settings"), add `127.0.0.1, localhost`.
6. Click "OK", then "Apply".

Once you've done that, OS X shouldn't route requests to localhost via your proxy, and Postman should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I already done this. The problem is that I use a vagrant VM and a nginx server to provide my API. I found found a way to bypass this problem.